# How to get data in table dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

How to get data dynamically in a table? I am not able to put my attempt as I don't know what to do. Please do not consider the given example:

```
<div id = "tbScore">
        <table border="1" style="width:500px">
          <tr>
               <td>Jill</td>
               <td>Smith</td> 
          </tr>

          <tr>
               <td>Jill</td>
               <td>Smith</td>       

          </tr>

          <tr>
               <td>Jill</td>
               <td>Smith</td>       

          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>        

          </tr>
          <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        

          </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: `Please do not consider given example` Well then why do you post it ? Your question is unclear, please edit question and post some relevant example of what you tried, what you want, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would get the row data of a table with the id of "myTable":

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
var rowLength = table.rows.length;
for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
   var cells = table.rows.item(i).cells;
   var cellLength = cells.length;

   for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){
      var cellVal = cells.item(j).innerHTML;
   }
}
```